# HailStone number issue

Tags: java

the hailstone sequence is a list of numbers that:
if n is even, n = n/2
if n is odd, n = (n * 3) + 1
if n is 1, the sequence ends.

Every time you do a step, you add +1 to the sequence. Im trying to find the largest sequence that is less than 1000. Here is my code.

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class HailStone
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int sequenceList = 0;
        int sequenceMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            while(count == 0)
            {

                int sequenceNum = i;

                if(sequenceNum == 1)
                {
                    sequenceList++;
                    sequenceMax = Math.max(sequenceMax, sequenceList);
                    count++;
                }

                if(sequenceNum % 2 == 0)
                {
                    sequenceList++;
                    sequenceNum = sequenceNum/2;

                }
                else if(sequenceNum % 2 != 0)
                {
                    sequenceList++;
                    sequenceNum = (sequenceNum * 3) + 1;

                }


            }

        }
        System.out.println("Max sequence: " + sequenceMax);
    }
}
```

My code compiles but it never finishes. I am probably missing something that is quite obvious but i've checked it over many times.

I know I could just use while(true) and break but I edited it to see if that was the issue. Don't criticize me on my format, all I need is why it's not working.

Comment: Your `sequenceNum` is always 0 in the first iteration of the for loop, so it'll never increment `count` and thus be stuck in the while loop.

Comment: Also think about this.  Say `n` is 24, then the next number in the sequence is 12, but you've already computed the sequence length for 12.  Do you really need to compute the whole sequence, or is there a better way to compute the sequence length for `n`=24?

Comment: I, of course, want to make it much more efficient as it has to do it 1000 times. I don't know any ways currently : also thanks for the tip. completely forgot it starts on 0! :)

Comment: "Im trying to find the largest sequence that is less than 1000" - what do you mean by that? a sequence for which the number of steps is < 1000 or a number < 1000 that starting from it we'll get the largest sequence?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting into an infinite loop because you start with:

```
int sequenceNum = 0;
```

and

```
count = 0;
```

so it keeps falling into the same `if` condition:

```
if(sequenceNum % 2 == 0)
{
    sequenceNum++;
    sequenceNum = sequenceNum/2;

}
```

so `sequenceNum` remains zero (0/2 == 0) and `sequenceNum` keeps increasing.

---

An alternative solution that caches previous results (as ajb suggested in one of the comments above):

```
class HailStone {

    static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        runMainLogic();
    }

    private static void runMainLogic() {
        int runner = 1;
        int maxSize = 0;
        int maxNum = 0;
        List<Integer> seq;
        while(runner < 1000) {
            if (cache.get(runner) == null) {
                seq = calcHailStone(runner);
                cache.put(runner, seq);
            } else {
                seq = cache.get(runner);
            }
            if (maxSize < seq.size()) {
                maxSize = seq.size();
                maxNum = runner;
            }
            runner ++;
        }
        System.out.println("maxNum = " + maxNum);
        System.out.println("maxSize = " + maxSize);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cache.get(maxNum).toArray()));
    }

    private static List<Integer> calcHailStone(int runner) {
        List<Integer> res = new LinkedList<>();
        while (true) {
            if (runner == 1) {
                res.add(1);
                break;
            } else if (runner % 2 == 0) {
                runner /= 2;
                res.add(runner);
            } else {
                runner = runner * 3 + 1;
                res.add(runner);                    
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```